# Basic backpack laravel install

Tags: laravel, elfinder

I'm following a few tutorials on how to setup Laravel backpack and I keep running into the same issue.

see-through nav bar:
[image]

As you can see in the picture the navbar is see-through and it happens whenever I try to extend it with `elfinder` or the `langfilemanager`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Check your console. Are there any stylesheets that are missing?

Comment: I do not see any stylesheets missing